# Issue with creating Sticky Div in fixed position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have tried to make a sticky DIV with the below code but it's not working as expected. When I scroll down, the DIV is sticky but its overlapping to the website Header as well as the Footer.
How to resolve this issue using CSS/JS?
Any help will appreciable.Thanks.

```css
.a{
    float: left;
    width: 67%;
}
.b{
    width: 32%;
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
.c{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
<div class="a">
-----
</div>
<div class="b">
-----
</div>
</div>
```

> -----

Comment: I am not able to visualize your issue.

Comment: It will overlap because position creates layers, manage accordingly

Comment: expanding on @AbhishekPandey comment, `position:fixed` removes it from the DOM so it will just be a fixed layer on the page and not have any effect on other elements.  Maybe give it a white background so other elements appear to vanish behind it.  You can also give it fixed dimensions, then use margins on other elements for the appearance that it is within the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for just scroll the page to see the sticky `div` what could be better is to run snippet in full page

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  progress = document.getElementsByClassName('b')[0];
  let height = window.pageYOffset;
  if (height > 395) {
    progress.style.position = 'fixed';
    progress.style.top = `${20}px`;
  } else {
    progress.style.position = 'absolute';
    progress.style.top = `${400}px`;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.b {
  width: 32%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  background: darkcyan;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
```

Comment: Got the solution Thanks for helping.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined it's showing when am scrolling each time on any page. Any solution for it